Persistent Authentication Cookie for External Membership Provider Umbraco 13
I've managed to implement full site single sign-on on my Umbraco site by extending an example on the Umbraco docs (https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/tutorials/add-microsoft-entra-id-authentication).
What I don't want is to have to present the login screen to the users, for them to have to manually click a 'sign in with ...' button every time they start a new session.
There does not appear to be an equivalent to the autoRedirect options that I have in the back-office Users configuration when dealing with front-end members, so I don't seem to be able to do that.
I'm trying instead to make the local authentication cookie persistent, much like adding a 'remember me' checkbox to a non-Umbraco login page.
There don't seem to be any options I can set in the OnExternalLogin even that's being set on the MemberExternalLoginProviderOptions instance, and there doesn't seem to be anything I can hook into on the OnTokenValidated event that's being set up when configuring the MemberAuthenticationBuilder.
I've tried adding a .AddCookie() method onto the memberAuthenticationBuilder, and followed advice I've seen on other posts to add services.ConfigureApplicationCookie() when configuring the app in Program/Startup.cs, with both set to add an expiry time to the cookie, but whatever I try, I'm still just getting the authentication cookie storing as a session cookie.
Has anyone else tried this, or does anyone know how I can either get a straight redirect to the OpenID provider (Entra in my case), or to persist the authentication cookie so that I can control how often the user needs to re-authenticate?
My last ditch attempt is likely to be a very hacky auto-submit of the login form, so the user still gets redirected to it, but a bit of JS automatically submits the form and takes them straight out to the external provider, but I really don't want to go down that route if I can avoid it.

So, it looks like persistent cookie is a no-go as a result of a hardcoded value within Umbraco itself.  https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/15f42f9ba99774aa57167db3f9519122ea87d7cf/src/Umbraco.Web.Website/Controllers/UmbExternalLoginController.cs#L101

I've found that there is a hardcoded 'isPersistent' value being passed into memberSignInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync from the UmbExternalLoginController that is always false (presumably on the basis that you'd want your OIDC service provider to own the lifespan of the authentication token), however, the impact of that is such that in a single-sign-on solution, the user's local authentication cookie would expire whenever their session ends, and would always be prompted with a login screen when hitting a non-public area of the site (in my case the homepage or any descendent), forcing them to click a login button for the chosen provider in order for the provider to perform that authentication is still valid.
In my instance, the simplest way around this was to take the code for the UmbExternalLoginController, and point my login partial to that custom controller instead.  In there, I was then able to control the isPersistent flag, and that, coupled with the services.ConfigureApplicationCookie call in my program.cs was enough to allow me to control the local authentication cookie's lifespan.
